# how to find max date and hour everyday by using hive query

Tags: hiveql

I am getting error as org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:168 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'max' '(' in expression specification while using max(date) and max(sum_hour)

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret correctly, you can do:

```
select max(datecol)
from t
group by year(datecol), month(datecol), day(datecol);
```

Comment: `trunc(...,'DD')` is not supported by Hive

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . Do you know why the documentation is incorrect ?  (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions)

Comment: The documentation is fine. `trunc` does exist, but check the "description" for the supported formats

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . Oh, that is an *exclusive* list.  I figured it was compatible with Oracle.  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. P.s. I like to verify these things against the source. Check line 429 https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFTrunc.java

Answer (score 0):

`date` is a reserved word.
Use `date` or even better, rename your column